# Error message = Process exited before completing request. Error = Pool is closed

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-rds, amazon-aurora

I have a Lambda function, Aurora db, DynamoDb. I am **fetching data from aurora db** and I am getting ***error for some read request and output for some read request***. This is the sample code, I have **connected to Reader Endpoint**

```
var AWS = require("aws-sdk");
var mysql = require('mysql');
const client = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient({region : 'eu-west-1'});
var connection  = mysql.createPool({
    host     : "*******************",
    user     : "*****",
    password : "******",
    database : "mydb",
    port     : "3306"
  });
exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
  //var id = parseInt(event.id);
    connection.query("select * from demo where id=3;", function (error, results, fields) {

        if (error) {

            if (error) throw error;
        } else {

            connection.end();

        }
}
);
};
```

Error:

```
Response:
{
  "errorMessage": "RequestId: 0c2d1a39-58d9-11e8-bef9-dbe1bfb0a080 Process exited before completing request"
}

Request ID:
"0c2d1a39-58d9-11e8-bef9-dbe1bfb0a080"

Function Logs:
START RequestId: 0c2d1a39-58d9-11e8-bef9-dbe1bfb0a080 Version: $LATEST
2018-05-16T07:16:27.041Z    0c2d1a39-58d9-11e8-bef9-dbe1bfb0a080    Error: Pool is closed.
```

***In some read req I get desired output but in some read request I get above error.*** Does anyone know solution? Please help....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Will you be able to move the following section to the inside of the function handler? This modification let the Lambda function to initialize the connection object every time instead of reusing it.

```
var connection  = mysql.createPool({
  host     : "*******************",
  user     : "*****",
  password : "******",
  database : "mydb",
  port     : "3306"
});
```

As per the [documentation](https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql) , Closing the connection is done using end() which makes sure all remaining queries are executed before sending a quit packet to the mysql server. As you execute end() function of connection object inside your Lambda function, I believe you will need to initialize the connection object at the beginning of your Lambda function as well.

Comment: Man, you saved my day! Thanks so much.